# Removing query_string from wildcard subdomain rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, query-string, subdomain, wildcard

My goal is to point:

`http://xyz.domain.com/abc` to `http://www.domain.com/dir/file.php?var=xyz`

(In other words, anything with `http://_____.domain.com/abc` would read from `http://www.domain.com/dir/file.php?var=_____`.)

I used this in my .htaccess file at the root of the website (http://www.domain.com/.htaccess):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^abc/*$ dir/file.php?var=%2 [NC,L]
```

It worked, but then it automatically redirected to `http://xyz.domain.com/abc/?var=xyz` when I just wanted `http://xyz.domain.com/abc` without the query string showing up.

I considered adding a `%{QUERY_STRING}` line to the above but got stuck when trying to match the two RewriteCond's `var`s to each other.

Then I found this at http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html#Removing_Query_String

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*\;.*\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule .* http://www.askapache.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

...which I'm guessing it's the right code to get rid of something like this on a regular domain? I tried making it suitable for wildcard subdomains by changing it to this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /.*\;.*\ HTTP/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com[NC]
RewriteRule .* http://%2.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}? [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't work. SO...can anyone help?

Comment: is there an "abc" directory in your document root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a Module called mod_dir that redirects the browser when it thinks you are trying to access a directory but are missing the trailing slash. When I test on my apache it only happens when the directory actually exists, I get redirected with a trailing slash, but the rewrite happens and I see the query string. Try forcing, internally, the trailing slash and when rewriting to dir/file, expressly use a trailing slash:

```
# Force trailing slash when accessing /abc without one
RewriteRule ^abc$ /abc/ [NC,L]

# these are the same
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.domain.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).domain.com [NC]
# Match against a trailing slash
RewriteRule ^abc/$ dir/file.php?var=%2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! And sorry, I guess it _was_ a real directory. In my head, I was thinking that I would be able to repeat this for ANY word for `abc`, directory or not. I understand it now.